# UWP code : using "await" in "Dispatcher"

Tags: windows, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

```cs
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.High,async () =>
{
    await MainPage.bmpsource.SetBitmapAsync(bmp);
});
```

I putted codes in while loop .When I click button or some controls on running app,the app will crash and pinpoint on code  "await MainPage.bmpsource.SetBitmapAsync(bmp);".

VS output:
there will be an exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
A task was canceled.
Maybe someone can help me,thank you!

Comment: While loop in a new Task not UI

Comment: `await` for `RunAsync` of an `async` lambda doesn't wait until the lambda completes; it only waits until `RunAsync` has completed its job. You would typically use a `TaskCompletionSource` and manually complete it if you want to wait for the lambda to complete.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [CoreDispatcherPriority.High](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcherpriority) as that can cause issues (and may be causing this issue).

Please check the link above for more information on this matter.

Comment: My app is used for showing the continuous images from Iot Camera. I used Camera API to get pixel data in a new task with a fetch loop.  When I get an image frame pixel data, I use eventhandler to informing UI to create softwarebitmapsource and ImageControl.source = softwarebitmapsource.    If i don‘t use High, the framerate of showing will reduce from 35 fps to 30 fps.    So ,do you have some idea can help me about showing continuous images, and make Image control  looking like playing video.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`CaptureElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CaptureElement) ?